# Exemplo de login com javascript

Tags: javascript, login, lógica

Como faço para esse login aceitar 3 usuários?
E sendo um usuário válido ele direcionar para o index?

```js
function Login() {
  var done = 0;
  var usuario = document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value;
  usuario = usuario.toLowerCase();
  var senha = document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value;
  seha = senha.toLowerCase();

  if (usuario == "bcf" && senha == "bcf") {
    window.location = "index.html";
    done = 1;
  }
  if (done == 0) {
    alert("Dados incorretos, tente novamente");

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container login col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
    <br />
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="title-login">Login</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form method="post">

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"> <i
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="width: auto"></i>

         </span> <input id="txtUsuario" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Usuário" required="" />

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"> <i
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style="width: auto"></i>
         </span> <input id="txtSenha" runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Senha" required="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Atenção!</strong> Usuário e/ou senha incorretos.
       </div-->
          <div>
            <input class="btn btn-xm btn-block btn-entrar" type="submit" value="Entrar" onclick="Login()" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você está digitando a senha em minúsculas?

Comment: As duas respostas atuais já mencionam isso, mas vou insistir: você está ciente que **a segurança desse método é zero**, certo? Qualquer um que saiba mexer no console do browser ou exibir o código fonte poderá ver a lista de login a senha. Não existe solução segura 100% em JS client-size, login é pra ser tratado no servidor.

Comment: Eu to apenas exercitando meu js por causa da faculdade

Comment: Ok Isa, só queria ter certeza de que você sabia o que estava fazendo. Vou manter a nota acima para desavisados que cheguem aqui pelo google.

Comment: Eu perguntei se você digita as senhas em minúsculas por causa disso: `seha = senha.toLowerCase();` - Observe que você usou `seha` sem a letra `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Eu colocaria os usuários válidos numa variável JSON.

Entretanto, o correto seria validar isso num *back-end*. Caso contrário, é muito fácil pegar as senhas de todo mundo e a segurança disso é zero.

Ah, note que no HTML, estou usando `onclick="return Login()"`. Esse `return` aí é muito importante. A função `Login()` retorna `true` ou `false`.

```js
var usuarios = [
    {"login": "bcf", "senha": "bcf"},
    {"login": "mamae", "senha": "abacaxi"},
    {"login": "papai", "senha": "melancia"},
];

function Login() {
    var usuario = document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value.toLowerCase();
    var senha = document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value;

    for (var u in usuarios) {
        var us = usuarios[u];
        if (us.login === usuario && us.senha === senha) {
            window.location = "index.html";
            return true;
        }
    }
    alert("Dados incorretos, tente novamente.");
    return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container login col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
    <br />
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="title-login">Login</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="width: auto"></i>
              </span>
              <input id="txtUsuario" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Usuário" required="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style="width: auto"></i>
              </span>
              <input id="txtSenha" runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Senha" required="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Atenção!</strong> Usuário e/ou senha incorretos.
          </div-->
          <div>
            <input class="btn btn-xm btn-block btn-entrar" type="submit" value="Entrar" onclick="return Login()" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Usei seu exemplo Mas ele continua não direcionando para outra página, pq?

Comment: @Isa Editei a resposta. E agora?

Comment: ainda não. a página dá uma atualizada mas volta para o login mesmo, não muda de página

Comment: @Isa O que era para ser o "index.html"? O teste que fiz aqui, ao digitar um dos três logins/senhas cadastrados, vai a uma página onde está escrito "*The custom error module does not recognize this error.*" - Ao digitar qualquer outra coisa, aparece o `alert`. O motivo disso é que ele tenta redirecionar para o "index.html" do stacksnippets (que é onde os exemplos de javascript do stackoverflow são executados), mas obviamente, eles não têm um "index.html". O que deveria acontecer se a senha for aceita?

Comment: eu criei uma outra pagina para redirecionar, e não acontece nada. Se o login fosse aceito teria que direcionar para outra pagina

Comment: @Isa O teste aqui, ao clicar no botão "Executar" acima funciona (mesmo que ele caia no "*The custom error module does not recognize this error.*")? Se sim, então o seu problema está em algum outro lugar do seu sistema que não o que você postou na pergunta. Se não, então eu gostaria de saber o que foi que aconteceu ao invés disso.

Answer (score 0):

O certo seria...

```js
function Login(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var usuario = document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value;
  usuario = usuario.toLowerCase();
  var senha = document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value;
  senha = senha.toLowerCase();

  if (usuario == "bcf" && senha == "bcf") {
    alert("dados corretos");
    window.location = "index.html";
  }else{
    alert("Dados incorretos, tente novamente");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container login col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
    <br />
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="title-login">Login</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form method="post">

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"> <i
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="width: auto"></i>

         </span> <input id="txtUsuario" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Usuário" required="" />

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"> <i
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style="width: auto"></i>
         </span> <input id="txtSenha" runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Senha" required="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--div class="alert lert-danger">
        <strong>Atenção!</strong> Usuário e/ou senha incorretos.
       </div-->
          <div>
            <input class="btn btn-xm btn-block btn-entrar" type="submit" value="Entrar" onclick="Login(event)" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>

</script>
```

Porém isso nunca deve ser implementado em produção.